# Using buttons to create them in new form

Tags: c#, button

So for my school project I have buttons on a form that when pressed open up a second form with their details on it. On that second form is another button that when pressed is supposed to add the first button on a third form. Would lists be a good way to go about it? I'm fairly new to C# and programming as a whole so I have no idea how to do this without entangling myself in my own code.

Comment: I recomend you to use Usercontrolls in WPF (https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/usercontrols-and-customcontrols/creating-using-a-usercontrol/ || https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/user-control-in-wpf/ )

Comment: A good way of learning this, is by trying it. If you fail, your knowledge grows. Start with something simpler if this is too difficult. If you walk into a problem in your code, share the code with a specific question. _"I have no idea how to do this without entangling myself in my own code."_ this is what you need to share. "There is no stupid code while learning."

Comment: are you using winforms or WPF, or is it left up you you?